# How do i add an custom post type to a new role created by the Members plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I have created a new role in the Members plugin, However that specific role needs to only have access to 2 custom post types i have created. These CPT's are created using the label tag.

The problem is that the custom post type doesn't show up on the members plugin when i want to assign it.

I tried using the capabilities tag but when i use that it does show up but when i login as the user assigned with that role it doesnt show the CPT in the nav bar of wordpress.

English isn't my first language so please excuse me if the formatting is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? If it works, can you please accept the answer? I could use the reputation points and it motivates to answer more questions... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign capabilities to that new role, in functions.php file:

```
function add_role_caps() {

//roles to add capabilities
$roles = array('YOUR-NEW-ROLE','editor','administrator');

//set capabilities for selected roles
foreach($roles as $role) {

$myrole = get_role($role);

$myrole->add_cap( 'read' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'read_MYCPT');
$myrole->add_cap( 'read_private_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'edit_MYCPT' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'edit_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'edit_others_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'edit_published_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'publish_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'delete_others_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'delete_private_MYCPTS' );
$myrole->add_cap( 'delete_published_MYCPTS' );

  }
}
add_action('admin_init','add_role_caps',999);
```

Just replace the CAPS values with your own. This answer assumes that the CPT was created with the optional plural descriptive name for the custom post type.